# How do I use the __str__ method within a class declaration to print a formatted string?

Tags: python, string, class

I checked the other similar question to this, but it's not asking nearly the same thing. My problem is that I'm trying to use a `__str__` method inside of a Python 3's *class* definition to access some variables that have already been passed into the class via the constructor.

When the class prints, I want it to print a formatted string with two variables inserted. When I pass the variables into the `__str__` declaration, I get one error. When I call the variables in the actual formatted string (with or without self-dot) I get two more errors.

The only way I know to make it work is to pass the specific variables into the `__str__` method header as default values `def __str__(self, name="john", age = 23):`

I know there's only one real way to do this. Am I supposed to use `__repr__` with `__str__` in order for it to work? Here's the source code:

```
class Tenderloin( ):

    def __main__(self, nameo = "none", age= 0, nation = "none", race = "none", personality = "none"):
    
        self.nameo = nameo;
        self.age = age;
        self.nation = nation;
        self.race = race;
        self.personality = personality;

    def __init__(self, nameo, age, nation, race, personality):
        print("Hi. My name is " + str(nameo) + ". I am " + str(age) + " years old.\nI come from " + str(nation) + " of the " + str      (race) + " race. My personality is " + str(personality));
    
    def __str__(self, name, age):
        return  f"This is  {str(self.nameo)},  {str(self.age)}.";
        

john = Tenderloin("John Jenkins", 23, "America", "black", "nice"); 
jellaye = Tenderloin("Jellaye Flabbaghan", 48, "Hindustand", "Crustasian", "bellowing");
print(str(john));
print(str(jellaye));    

gets = input("Please press Enter.");
```

Comment: I didn't understand what the problem is.

Comment: I'm new to the `__main__` method, what is its purpose?

Comment: `__main__` method is not used to define class objects. Please combine `__main__` and `__init__`.
`__main__` is used in scripts to denote the point where executions begins when running a file directly.

Comment: When you print a Tenderloin do you want to see what in `__str__` or the `__init__` ? why did you wrote 2 different representation

Comment: @mkrieger1: It's not a thing, so there's nothing to be new to. `__main__` only has meaning in two contexts: 1) It's the `__name__` assigned when a module is launched as the main script for a program, and 2) If you try to run a package (a directory), the `__main__.py` within it is what gets run. I think they don't actually understand what `__init__` is for, and are just throwing stuff at the wall until something sticks.

Comment: @yoonghm: To be clear, execution begins at the top of the file no matter what (it never *begins* anywhere else). `if __name__ == '__main__':` is used to *filter* which parts of the code are only executed when run as a script, as opposed to the parts run when imported as a module.

Comment: the `__str__` hook takes no arguments other than `self`, it isn't clear how you meant for that to work, and in any case, you don't even use the parameters in the function!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as existing `__main__` instance method (that name style is reserved for builtin methods), also the signature for the str method is `def __str__(self)` and you don't need to call explicit `str()` around inside a print.

The only use of `__main__` that you'll have is like this

```
class Tenderloin:

    def __init__(self, nameo="none", age=0, nation="none", race="none", personality="none"):
        self.nameo = nameo
        self.age = age
        self.nation = nation
        self.race = race
        self.personality = personality

    def __str__(self):
        return f"This is {self.nameo}, {self.age}."


if __name__ == '__main__':
    john = Tenderloin("John Jenkins", 23, "America", "black", "nice")
    jellaye = Tenderloin("Jellaye Flabbaghan", 48, "Hindustand", "Crustasian", "bellowing")
    print(john)
    print(jellaye)
```

And python doesn't need `;` at the end of lines

Comment: Just to be clear... whilst there is no well-known dunder method called \_\_main__  there's nothing to stop you creating such a method. It would be somewhat bizarre but it is what it is. Of course, it wouldn't do anything unless you explicitly called it

Comment: @DarkKnight the naming `__methodname__` is by convention reserved to builtin method, that's what i meant

Comment: But it is, as you say, merely a convention. That was my point

Answer (score 0):

This should work now.

```
class Tenderloin( ):

    def __init__(self, nameo = "none", age= 0, nation = "none", race = "none", personality = "none"):
        self.nameo = nameo
        self.age = age
        self.nation = nation
        self.race = race
        self.personality = personality

        print("Hi. My name is " + str(nameo) + ". I am " + str(age) + " years old.\nI come from " + str(nation) + " of the " + str      (race) + " race. My personality is " + str(personality))
    
    def __str__(self):
        return  f"This is  {str(self.nameo)},  {str(self.age)}."
        

john = Tenderloin("John Jenkins", 23, "America", "black", "nice"); 
jellaye = Tenderloin("Jellaye Flabbaghan", 48, "Hindustand", "Crustasian", "bellowing")
print(str(john))
print(str(jellaye))

gets = input("Please press Enter.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I inadvertently answered my own question for a second time. I had a working version of the Python class with the **str** method in a jupyter notebook, but I didn't have an internet connection at the time so I couldn't review it. Basically, the **str** method that formats a string for printing the object is only meant to be used in jupyter notebooks (and maybe VBC, I'm not sure). It's not supposed to be used for someone who's just dinking around in a PY file in Notepad. Yes, I do most of my programming in Notepad.

Comment: "printing the object is only meant to be used in jupyter notebooks (and maybe VBC, I'm not sure). It's not supposed to be used for someone who's just dinking around in a PY file in Notepad." that really makes no sense.

Comment: I was trying to "print" the object as  a pre-formatted string (you can't print a class directly) and I was having trouble getting it to work in my py file, but it did work in my Jupyter Notebook.